# Display products using custom product relation - magento2.1.2

Tags: magento-2.1.1

I just added a new custom product relation called **customtype** along with Related Products, Up-Sells, Cross-Sells. So how can I retrieve and display products in details page as a separate block under upsell products.
while looking into **app/design/frontend/m2/winter/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/items.phtml** and checking type using **$block->getType()**, shows only related and upsell types. So how to make it possible for getting customtype and products ?

Comment: Did you assign products to the custom grid?